# Count the total number of pendingDocumentWrites in a Firestore Collection

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to get the count of documents in a collection with pendingwrites. For unsent messages counter.

I did this but, every time I add a new message the count gets set back to one.

```java
listener = firestore.collection("Chats").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {

    int count = 0;

    for(DocumentChange change : value.getDocumentChanges){

        if(!change.getDocument().getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()
            // Do some stuff
        } else {
            count ++;
        }

    }
    setCounter(count);

}
```

Comment: It's likely your `int count=0;` keeps resetting the values, try setting a global count instead.

Comment: I could make it global but then how am I supposed to reduce it when the message gets sent? @AliasCartellano

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: That is in my chat application. So assume while I'm chatting to someone I get disconnected from the internet for a while and the `count` increases to say 5 for the messages I sent while being offline. And then i get back online the messages get sent but the `count` is still at 5. Further more, if send more messages while offline the `count` is only going to increase. I can't just reduce `count` when the change/added document doesn't have pending writes as that message might not be sent by me. Then how to properly reduce the `count`? @AliasCartellano

Comment: So clearing `count` in `if(!change.getDocument().getMetadata().hasPendingWrites())` wouldn't work? I'm also confused by "that message might not be sent by me" means.

Comment: Have opted into metadata updates (via [INCLUDE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/MetadataChanges#INCLUDE))?